# What's the difference between mobile first and non mobile first responsive layout?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

Well, I'm not sure I got the difference between `mobile first` and `non mobile first` responsive layout?

This is what I know, and probably something is not right:

1. Use Media queries with CSS (also for non mobile first layout)
2. Create a layout by starting from mobile and not from desktop version

I've saw there's a difference between `bootstrap` setting and `foundation` setting, is it important for that difference?

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<!-- I've read it's not mobile first -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- Foundation -->
<!-- I've read it's mobile first -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

At the end that's all I know, is there something more to know about it?
Where i can find a good guide?

Comment: Mobile first means designing for mobile and expanding, the opposite is true for non mobile first. Also, this is not really a question for this site, and there are plenty of resources you can find with a simple search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as it says....

"mobile first" and "non-mobile first" layout.

Mobile first means from the start, it is made to look how you want it to look in mobile. Then in most cases you then use min-width media query to adjust according to larger screen sizes.

Non-Mobile first means you design it for desktop or large screens first. Then in most cases using max-width media query to go back and make it look better in smaller/mobile screens.

I hear there are problems with browser's understanding min-device-width and max-device-width. Just use min-width and max-width.

If your designing a responsive theme, it is best to start mobile first.

Watch This Video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-BVmrSG93XE

Comment: Mobile-first seems to lead to websites that, when viewed on a desktop, are clunky and difficult to use because most of the screen is wasted with blank space, page elements are far too large with too much space between them, and lots of scrolling is needed.  This is no doubt laziness from the developers, but why make your website much harder to use for 50% of your audience?  RD should optimize your site for all devices.  Which first should be a superfluous question.

Comment: For anyone looking for further discussion/opinions, see this comment thread: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/69613/155788

Answer (score 2):

Article [here](http://gomakethings.com/mobile-first-and-internet-explorer/) provides important details.

**What is mobile first?**

Mobile first, from a coding perspective, means that your base style is typically a single-column, fully-fluid layout. You use @media (min-width: whatever) to add a grid-based layout on top of that.

The alternative – desktop first – involves starting with a wide, grid-based layout, and using @media (max-width: whatever) to scale down to a single-column layout.

**Why mobile first?**

iPhone and Android browsers are quite capable, but older smart phones, feature phones and other small-screen devices like gaming consoles may not support media queries.

Imagine trying to read tiny text in a big screen layout on an old, underpowered feature phone.

Mobile first web design extends progressive enhancement to site layout, allowing you to serve simple, readable content to all devices, and layer on structure and presentation for more capable devices.

**An example of Mobile First from the latest Dreamweaver 6 Fluid Layout is as below** -

```
/* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. NOTE: No Media Query line here*/

.gridContainer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 87.36%;
    padding-left: 1.82%;
    padding-right: 1.82%;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout.*/
/* NOTE: Now from here media query lines are added for Tablets and Desktop */

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
.gridContainer {
    width: 90.675%;
    padding-left: 1.1625%;
    padding-right: 1.1625%;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
}

/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
.gridContainer {
    width: 88.2%;
    max-width: 1232px;
    padding-left: 0.9%;
    padding-right: 0.9%;
    margin: auto;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
}
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**: Another article [here](http://www.scripttheweb.com/design/css-media-queries-beginners-guide/) which explains above example with a little more details. Excerpt as below -

> Progressive Queries
>
> Since some older mobile devices may not support media queries at all,
>   bottling up the small version of your CSS rules inside a query may
>   keep it from recognizing what CSS it can render within it. Instead of
>   this, it may be a good idea to have the smaller version be the
>   "default", while adding in the additional CSS rules for larger screens
>   via media queries (since desktop browsers are more likely to recognize
>   the media queries).
>
> Supporting IE and older browsers
>
> - [css3mediaqueries.js](http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/)
> - [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)

Comment: This is wrong and always has been.  Mobile browsers have recognized `@media` rules long before IE.  They were developed primarily to support small-screen devices.  In 2013, for a cross-platform site you would use `@media` `max-width` for small-screen CSS so your site would still work in IE on desktops.  Do it the other way round and IE users would have been screwed.  Thankfully and not before time we can now ditch IE8 support.

Answer (score 1):

With a mobile first viewpoint, we start by loading the absolute bare essentials on the smaller platforms. This leads to a snappier experience that avoids unnecessary lag. The additional resources are loaded strictly on an as-neeeded basis to platforms that can handle them well.

[image]

Look at:
http://www.slideshare.net/splashomnimedia/desktopfirst-vs-mobilefirst-web-design